# Link to anchor on current page with smooth scroll

Tags: 7, routes, javascript

I have smooth scrolling working (https://drupal.org/project/scroll_to_destination_anchors) and I have linking to anchors working (https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) but I can't get my desired result of clicking a menu item and then scrolling to the anchor. I only need this to work on the current page - if the anchor is on another page, I am ok with the menu item loading the other page and jumping (not scrolling) to that anchor.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using the [Void Menu](https://drupal.org/project/void_menu) module and using the id of the anchor as one of the void options.

For example, my menu item says "`<void2>`" where void2 contains the id of the div `"#aboutus"`.

Comment: For future reference, if needed, we did similar here: http://lockouttagoutprocedures.com/. But the main menu merely has <front>#anchor. This way Drupal has a valid menu path, but still an anchor destination.